# A way to count logged in users and display count?

Tags: users, login

Is there a possibility to get the count of users currently logged in and display it somewhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the logged in users using wp_get_current_user(); . 
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_current_user

But your probably better off just using a plugin or looking at the the following plugins code.
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-useronline/

Comment: This is plain wrong. your answer points the OP to a function that gets the data for the current session for the current user only. No info about the other sessions of other users are available through that function: This function does nothing to help you count the currently opened sessions.